# Misalligned attributes using bit-fields in C++ class

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I'm trying to use bit-fields in C++ to achieve a specific class size, but for some reason it's bigger than I expected.

The problem is, a class with 32 bits (4 bytes) is reporting (when passed as argument to `sizeof`) 5 bytes. Example class bellow:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned int u32;

class Test {
    u8 four_bit_field : 4;
    u8 eight_bit_field;
    u32 twenty_bit_field : 20;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

If the `four_bit_field` and `eight_bit_field` positions are switched, `sizeof` return the proper size, 4 bytes. I believe that it's problably a memory allignment problem.

So, someone knows the reason behind this behaviour? And, most importantly, how can I fix this, without switching any positions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `u8` field without a bit count is being aligned to the next byte boundary, rather than being packed with the other bit fields. Thus your first 4 bits take a byte, the second 8 bits take a byte, and the last 20 bits take 3 bytes, totaling 5.

If you add a bit field size to the 8 bit field it will work, see http://ideone.com/Bexw6l

Comment: That's what I thought when I said this is a memory allignment problem. But i'm looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: @braunmagrin, I was busy testing the solution, see my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry for the rush. Thanks, that solved.

Answer (score 2):

It is, indeed, a problem of alignment. `u8 eight_bit_field` is not a bitfield, it's a plain `unsigned char` (from the name), and a `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char` is naturally aligned on a byte boundary.

You therefore end up with `4` bits of padding between `four_bit_field` and `eight_bit_field` and `4` bits of padding after `twenty_bit_field`; the latter possibly reusable by a derived class, the former forever lost.

Answer (score 2):

Try forcing the alignment to 1 byte:

```
#pragma pack(1)
class Test {
    u8 four_bit_field : 4;
    u8 eight_bit_field : 8;
    u32 twenty_bit_field : 20;
};
#pragma pack()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the `#pragma` directives.
Always learning...